# GAS dynamic maps

Tags: google-apps-script

The GAS map tutorial covers staticmaps, but can you create a dynamic map with zoom and pan capability?  Is this a limitation of GAS versus the full Maps API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [issue on the Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1447). Summary: The functionality is not available now, but it may be in the near future.